# Matlab allow access to folder for mkdir

Tags: matlab, permissions

I'm trying to make some directories and copy some files into a folder in "C:\Program Files\myFolder\"

When I try `mkdir('C:\Program Files\myFolder')` I get the following error:

```
Error using mkdir
Access is denied.
```

Is there anyway (dynamically) to give matlab write access to this folder? Perhaps using system commands?

Comment: Permissions are at the user level. This means that: if there is a way to do it through Matlab it would be an overkill, or if there was it would constitute a potential security threat. Also, what's your OS?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Windows (7 & 8).  Is it possible to run a function in "administrator mode" or something similar? Perhaps it will work if you start matlab in administrator mode?

Answer (score 3):

This is possible (on windows 7/8) by running matlab in administrator mode. Right click on your matlab shortcut and select "Run as administrator".  Click yes on the pop-up box.  When you run the script it will not result in the above error.